# Is asking for a design 'open data', i.e. on topic?

Tags: discussion, support

In [this question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10324/whare-can-i-find-earthquake-resistant-school-design-in-africa) the OP is looking for *designs for school construction*.

Does that fall in the scope of the site?

If it does, it seems people can ask for *any* digitally stored (not copyrighted) material - that is *open* and *data* after all. Even information on paper (i.e. a reference to a book) would be fine.

Quoting from the help center:

> Open data, as defined by the Open Definition, is any kind of data that can be freely used, modified, and shared by anyone for any purpose.

and

> Data requests ("Where can I find data about … ?") are usually welcome for any topic

Maybe *data* should be limited to more than one data point?

Comment: I concur, the blueprint would be a type of data, but it is difficult to say this would be available. It would be like asking for the data on Death Star design... I allowed it to stay open, but feel that it will be another non-answer on the Open Data pile.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Is it a request for what falls under this site's definition of 'open data', that is: is the question on topic?

Answer (score 1):

i'm incredibly biased in my opinion here, but i think this is a fair request for open data.
in general, unless it seems like a poster is asking for help with their homework, or more technical than od, i'm inclined to let it be.
i do think that sites that outsource support here fall under specific guidelines, but that conversation continually evades me.